# How do I sort the values in a single table row? (i.e. sort horizontally)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is simple but for some reason, wasn't so simple for me finding an answer.

All I want to do is sort the cells of a table row - for lack of a better description - 'horizontally', not 'vertically'. Everything I've found so far deals with sorting individual columns or sorting based on column headers etc.

There are no headers, just a simple table such as this.

```html
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <td>Sample-N</td>
        <td>Sample-W</td>
        <td>Sample-A</td>
        <td>Sample-K</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample-S</td>
        <td>Sample-U</td>
        <td>Sample-J</td>
        <td>Sample-M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample-O</td>
        <td>Sample-E</td>
        <td>Sample-L</td>
        <td>Sample-B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then after sorting, it should appear like this:

```html
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <td>Sample-A</td>
        <td>Sample-K</td>
        <td>Sample-N</td>
        <td>Sample-W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample-J</td>
        <td>Sample-M</td>
        <td>Sample-S</td>
        <td>Sample-U</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample-B</td>
        <td>Sample-E</td>
        <td>Sample-L</td>
        <td>Sample-O</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If an answer already exists (preferably using jQuery), can someone please point me in the right direction? Because I can't find it.

Even the tablesorter plug-in only seems to sort individual columns.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon that would be sorting vertically, he wants horizontal sorting.

Comment: http://www.datatables.net/ should work for that

Comment: @MattK I see, i totally misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an array of the elements, sort them with a custom sorting method (using `String.localeCompare` to compare the text contents) then append the items back into their parent in the correct order.

```js
$('#t1 tr').each(function(){
    var $tr = $(this),
        $tds = $tr.children(),
        tdArray = $.makeArray($tds);

    tdArray.sort(function(a, b){
        return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
    });

    $.each(tdArray,function(i, el){
        $(el).appendTo($tr);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <td>Sample-N</td>
        <td>Sample-W</td>
        <td>Sample-A</td>
        <td>Sample-K</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample-S</td>
        <td>Sample-U</td>
        <td>Sample-J</td>
        <td>Sample-M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample-O</td>
        <td>Sample-E</td>
        <td>Sample-L</td>
        <td>Sample-B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

As **@Karl-André Gagnon** points out, this can be shortened to just

```
$('#t1 tr').each(function(){
    $(this).children().sort(function(a, b){
        return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
    }).appendTo(this);
});
```

because jQuery returns an array-like object from `.children()` that contains the native `.sort()` method of a regular array. I would personally not use this version due to relying on that method being included in the returned object, and instead go with the `$.makeArray()` solution that creates a native array which is sure to contain the sort method.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I wanted to provide an example that makes the basic prinicple understandable, and not the shortest way to achieve it.